# Add dynamic link on Contacts in Lightning

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-link

I'm trying to add a link to an outside url (in this case LinkedIn) which includes the contacts first and last name. 
Something like:

```
url_pre+{!Contact.Firstname} + "+" + {!Contact.LastName} + url_post
```

It seems like this should be simple to do under Actions/Buttons/Links but Lightning doesn't like Javascript or url buttons from my research and previous attempts.

What is the best/easiest way to do this in Lightning? I'm specifically looking for something that involves as little effort/clicks on the UI as is practical.

Comment: You can use force:navigteToURL. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check this link as per the salesforce notes the URL buttons are now getting supported,

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_url_button_support_lex.htm

Well I think I have got the trick for you. I enabled lightning in my org and I created a formula field of text type. And used this formula

HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com", "Linkedin", "_blank")

This formula jumped me out of Salesforce to google in a new tab.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: And now I feel stupid, I was looking in the wrong place for where it put the URL link in the layout. It said header and I instantly assumed it'd be at the top of the page.